# What might be the best time or place to return to Earth?

Tags: internal-consistency

My communities  are capable of returning to Earth in  Earth's past. They may go to more than one place or time, but the idea is that they will influence humankind to  be population and eco-savvy, in advance of mass over population or pollution. Some of the people may have technology that would possibly be from the year 3000, but most of the re-settlers do not. The reason is that the attempt to seed other planets has failed and the only chance for Humankind is to stop Earth from being destroyed by humans.

It almost has to be a religion, but where do I place the returnees for maximum 'bang'?

That is where back in time comes into play, it has to be pre-industrial. There are approximately a thousand, but that is flexible . They have to filter through a space and that limits the number  of resettlers.

North America was likely populated too late. My main protagonists started in the UK, so I would be happy to return them there. In fact, that is my preference. Is it a likely spot?

Thanks for all the answers. One gave me the idea I am going with. I've decided that the axiom 'you can lead a horse to water but you can't make him drink', is where I am going. I choose 6000 BCE in Jordan near Solomon's Mines. I'll need copper for 'my' LENR.

Comment: "Maximum bang" is extremely opinion based; there's no good way to judge a standard between any three people. Stack Exchange sites, World Building included, avoid such questions that have answers that can't be objectively (or semi-objectively) judged, as they provide poor future resources. Could you please define in concrete terms what you're exactly looking for?

Comment: I did want opinion. Go ahead and delete it. 'Is it a likely spot' was as close as I could get.

Comment: This might be more answerable if you were to define more clearly you community (number of people, tech level, what time they're coming from, etc.) as well as the level of influence.  There are millions of people today who want to achieve this, but have yet to succeed.

Comment: If I may, I'd like to suggest an edit to clarify the question: "I need a place in pre-industrial UK where 1000 people from the future can settle down without drawing attention, but not to cut off from society." As your question is very open ended as is. Narrow it down a bit and the responses will be more useful.

Comment: No spot will work. Any pre-industrial society following some eco-friendly religion are going to be literally run over by other cultures with more aggressive industries. Remember that the Industrial Revolution did not occur with the sole purpose of pollution but instead implemented vastly more efficient processes than pre-industrial times.

Comment: @Kys, luckily there is the fiction facctor...

Comment: thanks for the help, I think I have to come up with another idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Any Time Your Settlers Can Dominate

I think one possibility is that any time is good enough, pre-industrial, but the key would be that the settlers would have to choose a time & place where they could be *the* dominant force driving technological and ecological policy.

I'm envisioning something like an actual Illuminati society, where the settlers make use of their superior technology and historical knowledge to constantly guide humanity towards proper development.

One issue is the fact that governments frequently have ultra top secret research and development programs, and they can direct societal development via covert manipulation of dissemintion & repression of knowledge & technology. So, your settlers will have to infiltrate them or be them, otherwise the goverment might derail the settler's agenda.

So, overwhelming superiority in terms of money, power, influence, technology, knowledge, etc. would be key for establishing and maintaining your agenda.

### Maintain Permant Dominance

One last thing is how to make sure your settler's efforts are maintained over time. For example, if they do go back to the Pliocene, they may have to maintain a constant dominant influence all the way up to modern day, otherwise ignorance, shortsightedness and error can easily creep in and derail the plans. So, some plan for long-term maintenance of whatever strategy is implemented will be critical.

Comment: I think I will allow my settlers to return with a power source that only they can replicate. The problem would include keeping them honest because as we know power corrupts. I do have an idea for that. Thank you, I have some thinking to do.

Answer (score 6):

Obviously the best time to return to Earth and create a human civilization in accordance with whatever ideology is around the middle of the [Pliocene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pliocene), about 4 million years BP. The world is generally similar to ours with animals and plants very much like we have today, but the evolution of the genera *Australopitecus* and *Homo* has not yet begun. Just populate the world with ideologically suitable humans, with no competition, and make sure that no competition arises -- maybe make the Great Rift valley some sort of managed park.

Answer (score 3):

The UK is probably as good a place as any, since the industrial revolution began in Great Britain, and because of the ties to other parts of Europe any influence you have will trickle out from there.

You'd probably want to set up outside of the major population centers like London to begin with, and then as you gain a foothold send in people to set up shops.

Focus on ways to burn coal cleaner and more efficiently, and introduce other processes over time to keep industry on track, but with less impact on nature.

Comment: I might add a better way to industrialise, but have to figure that part out. My resettlers will have knowledge, but knowing is not the same as making it happen. Thanks.